# Game disk is broken! Can i get a disk from another region and play?

Tags: ps4

My friend broke his bf4 disk. He's from Canada and he came to live here in lebanon.

The disk he's got is from Canada and he's got the dlcs and all the updates so he doesn't want to go through with downloading them again.

Can he just buy a disk from Lebanon (Europe region) and run the game with the disk or does he have to reinstall the game to be able to run it?

Thanks for any speedy answers!

Comment: You can definitely play the game, since the PS4 is not region-locked. DLCs are probably not going to work (at least I know DLC and games have to be from the same region on the PS3, not sure about the PS4). As for whether you have to reinstall the game and if savegames will still be usable, I honestly don't know.

Comment: I know about it being region free. I'm just saying that he doesn't want to uninstall his already installed version. Can he play the game using the disk he buys from Lebanon (different region)

Comment: IDK, but if he's a risk for breaking the disk he could just get the full [digital release](https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-us/games/battlefield-4/cid=UP0006-CUSA00110_00-BATTLEFIELD40000?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=pscom&utm_campaign=pscom-UP0006-CUSA00110_00-BATTLEFIELD40000&smcid=ps:battlefield-4-ps4:up0006-cusa00110_00-battlefield40000:ps-ps4-games-battlefield-4-ps4.html) and then there are no issues. It's on sale now for $29 for PSN members and $36 regular.

Comment: Internet here sucks. 1mbit speed with a 40gb monthly cap

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work we tried it with a friend's disk. The console installs the game like its a new game so now he has 2 bf4s installed which is weird I guess. Resolved

Answer (score 1):

You have to uninstall and install back again. It's annoying.
I just got ghosts region 2 and I already had it updated and installed region 1. They wanted me to reupdate with the install.